# AWS Cost Explorer discrepancy for Root and linked account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

I'm pretty new to the cost explorer and looking at this scenario:
There's a root(organization) account which has multiple linked accounts like this:

```
Root Account
 - Account B
 - Account C
 - ...
```

When I filter a specific Account (`AccountB`) from the Root account, I see a cost discrepancy comparing to the view from `AccountB` itself.

here's the image to demonstrate the issue better :

- `Root account` view, filtered by `Linked AccountB`:
  [image]
- View from `AccountB` itself:
  [image]

Any idea/suggestions why I see this discrepancy ? (anything else I need to do to get the same cost for `AccountB` and `root->AccountB` ?)

Comment: May be check your `Taxes` and `Refund`? Do you have some `Saving Plans` on compute resources?

Comment: yea I have `saving plans` on compute resources ... son those plans are not shown from `root -> linked account` view then ? (I haven't found the doc for this yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Saving plans` are actually shown in both views, but `EDP` and `Private Rate card discounts` are only shown on the root account.